# How to fetch data with get method from an api and loop throw it?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, foreach

I make a function and use http:get in order to fetch from an api, but as it is associative array it is hard to reach end of element such as title, how can solve it?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class apiTest extends Controller
    {
        function data()
        {
            $get = http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
             $data = $get ->json();
                foreach ($data as $key => $datas) {
                    foreach ($datas as $key => $value){
                        echo $value;
                    }
                }
    
        }
     
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the second foreach ``foreach ($data as $post) {echo $post['title']; }``

Answer (score 1):

```
function data() {
    $get = http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    $data = $get->json();
    
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        echo $item['title'];
    }
}
```

Note that in your original code, you used the same variable name `$key` for both loops. It's important to use unique variable names for each loop to avoid conflicts.